# iOS Media Library: React to Access Apple Music Alert

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, avfoundation, uialertcontroller

iOS 10 now dictates that all applications that attempt to access the device's music library contain a `NSAppleMusicUsageDescription` within their `info.plist` that describes the intentions the application has for accessing it. Upon the application's first launch iOS prompts the user with this alert:

[image]

**QUESTION**

My application has logic that needs to execute upon user selection of either "OK" or "Don't Allow". How do I react to this alert that I didn't present myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use MediaLibrary.MPMediaLibrary.authorizationStatus() to determine if the user granted access or not.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I am still not sure how to react to the button press (Maybe I could still use the alert view's delegate methods). But assuming your solution works if all else fails maybe upon app launch I could repeatedly fire a timer that checks agains the authorization status that you suggest. I will try this later tonight and report back with my findings.

Comment: While though not an idle solution - I call to a method every second where I check if the status is `.authorized`, if so I reload my data. If the user chose no the check continues. But a button is present at the bottom of the view controller that will fast-app-switch to the settings for the app to allow access to the music library. When the user returns to the app, the check continues and will return `.authorized` within one second and I prompt the user that the music library is being refreshed.